# Python: key type should be immutable in dictionary, but why I can let an instance of node class be a key?

Tags: python, dictionary

No matter the dictionary in python or hash map in Java, the key can be an instance of node class.

But when I am reading the python tutorial, it says:

> Keys are unique within a dictionary while values may not be. The values of a dictionary can be of any type, but the keys must be of an immutable data type such as strings, numbers, or tuples.

Feel confused! # Sorry for my poor expression!:(

Sample code is:

```
class RandomListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.label = x
        self.next = None
        self.random = None

dict = {}
node1 = RandomListNode(10)
node2 = RandomListNode(5)
dict[node1] = node2
print dict[node1].label #5
```

Summary:
Hashable (hash value will not be changed) or immutable object can be key value.
Ref:
https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable

Comment: What ... what are you asking?  Are you asking if you can use a custom class as a dictionary key?  Are you trying to and failing?  Does your class implement the `__hash__` method?

Comment: Confused about what, exactly? What Node class are we talking about here?

Comment: That's just how the Python folks decided to design their Dictionary.  When you think about it, it does make sense.  Keys should always be some sort of unique value type.  I don't remember ever using a reference type as a key in a dictionary, regardless of the language.

Comment: Answer in comment because question was stupidly closed:  By default instances of a class are unique, and so can be used as keys.  The actual constraint is the presence of a `__hash__` method in the class.  If you add a custom `__eq__` method you must also add your own `__hash__` method to still be considered "immutable" -- but make sure your hash value does not change with mutation, or your entries will not be retrievable from `set`s and `dict`s!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default instances of a class are unique, and so can be used as keys.

The actual constraint is the presence of a `__hash__` method in the class. If you add a custom `__eq__` method you must also add your own `__hash__` method to still be considered "immutable" -- but make sure your hash value does not change with mutation, or your entries will not be retrievable from `set`s and `dict`s.

Comment: Thank you so much! But forgive that I am a new python learner,

Comment: @summer:  Nothing to forgive, your question was fine.  Good luck!